# savedInstanceState is null on back from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an issue wherein on hitting back button to move back to original activity, the saved instance state in oncreate method of fragment is null. The same code works perfectly fine if orientation of screen changes i.e. savedinstance state is not null. I am newbie to android so please assist.

My fragment code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Movie Detail Fragment - Saved Instance state is not null");
        detailMovie = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_KEY);
    } else {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Movie Detail Fragment - oncreate - saved instace state is null");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Movie Detail Fragment - onSaveInstanceState is called");
    if(movieDetails != null){
        detailMovie = new ArrayList<MovieDetail>();
        detailMovie.add(new MovieDetail(MOVIE_KEY, movieDetails));
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_KEY, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) detailMovie);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Movie Detail Fragment - detail movie is not null - " +movieDetails.length);
    } else {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Movie Detail Fragment - detail movie is null");
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_list"
    android:editable="false" />

</LinearLayout>

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomDetailAdapter - getView");
    if (convertView == null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomDetailAdapter - getView - convertview null");
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_details, parent, false);
    }
    final String[] values = details.get(position);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomDetailAdapter - getView - convertview is not null. Position - " +position);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_pic);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_textview1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_textview2);
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_textview3);
    TextView textView4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_textview4);
    Button buttonView =  (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_reviews);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomDetailAdapter - getView - item: Hello Click");
            if(context instanceof DetailActivity){
                Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomDetailAdapter - instance of detail activity");
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieReviewerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("moviedetails", values);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "Movie Detail Fragment - CustomDetailAdapter - starting review");
        }
    });
    if (values != null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomDetailAdapter - values is not null");
        Picasso
                .with(context)
                .load(values[0])
                .fit()
                .into(imageView);
        textView1.setText(values[1]);
        textView2.setText(values[2]);
        textView3.setText(values[3]);
        textView4.setText("Rating: " + values[4]);
        buttonView.setText("Reviews");
    } else {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomDetailAdapter - values is null");
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Are you handling `onBackPressed` on your second Activity? You should not need to  handle it, as `onCreate` wont be called when coming back from another activity

Comment: No I am not handling onBackPressed on second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Only when system kills your activity or fragment,then `onSaveInstanceState` will be invoked,and when you recreate the activity or fragment,system will pass what you put in `onSaveInstanceState` to `onCreate(Bundle)`,so if you jump from Acticity A or Fragment A to ActivityB or FragmentB,the `onSaveInstanceState` method will not be called,then extra arguments in `onCreate` will be null.
    Next is Why " if orientation of screen changes i.e. savedinstance state is not null.",that is because when your orientation of screen changes,your Activity will be killed by system and recreate(if you didn't set the android),so you should know why savedInstance is not null.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I jump to another activity on onclick below is the code snippet. I validated that onsaveinstancestate is being called on onclick.

Comment: You mean  `outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_KEY, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) detailMovie);
` has been invoked but `onSaveInstancestate` in `onCreate` is null?

Comment: yes thats right...based on log message i validated that.

Comment: See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))